# SQL Server 2000 change tracking

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have about a dozen related tables that I have suppose to implement a tracking system for. I cannot use triggers or trace. I am also specific the the types of changes that I have to track such as a certain type of user. How would I get started?

Comment: also the database I use is a backup copy of the day before.

Comment: First: **upgrade** to a recent version of SQL Server !! SQL Server 2000 is hopelessly outdated, unsupported, insecure - don't waste your time on doing more work on that obsolete platform ....

Comment: done, we are upgrading to sql2008 next week

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:
[Track Data changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx)